# NHibernate select most recent record that meets criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, provider

Last night I started working on an NHibernate provider.  I'm creating a criteria that several records will match, however I only want to return the most recent record (the record with the largest Id).  I thought UniqueResult() would do this it cannot be used if a list would be returned otherwise.

I could theoretically select the full list and then return the desired record, but I believe there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you add an Order?

```
ICriteria cr = Session.CreateCriteria<MyType>();

cr.AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id"));

MyType justone = cr.UniqueResult();
```

Comment: Yes but I'm still returned a list.  I only want to get a single object

Comment: You can use in conjunction with `UniqueResult()`. See my update.

Comment: You are right, I misinterpreted the shorthand.  I'll give you the correct answer and leave mine below so those in a similar situation can see the full method body.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is ultimately what was required.  It was actually a combination of a couple of things I had earlier tried.

```
MyObject mo = (MyObject)_session.CreateCriteria(typeof(MyObject))
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Property", value))
                .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id"))
                .SetMaxResults(1).UniqueResult();
            Log.Info(this, string.Format("Retrieving latest MyObject {0}.", mo.Name));
            return mo;
```